# What does sort() do in MongoDB when sorting by a sub-field in an array?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query

Imagine having a Mongo collection like this:

```
[
  {  
     "roleName":"slave",
     "id":2,
     "__uc__roleName":"SLAVE",
     "_children":{  
        "managers":[  

        ]
     },
     "_id":ObjectId("5508e3e5875cbdcc712feda6"),
     "_clean":true
  },

  {  
     "__uc__roleName":"BOSS",
     "_children":{  
        "managers":[  
           {  
              "name":"Tony",
              "surname":"Mobily",
              "roleId":0,
              "id":0,
              "__uc__name":"TONY",
              "__uc__surname":"MOBILY",
              "_children":{  

              }
           }
        ]
     },
     "_clean":true,
     "_id":ObjectId("5508e3a9875cbdcc712feda4"),
     "id":0,
     "roleName":"boss"
  },

  {  
     "__uc__roleName":"EMPLOYEE",
     "_children":{  
        "managers":[  
           {  
              "name":"Chiara",
              "surname":"Mobily",
              "roleId":1,
              "id":1,
              "__uc__name":"CHIARA",
              "__uc__surname":"MOBILY",
              "_children":{  

              }
           },
           {  
              "name":"Sara",
              "surname":"Fabbietti",
              "roleId":1,
              "id":2,
              "__uc__name":"SARA",
              "__uc__surname":"FABBIETTI",
              "_children":{  

              }
           },
           {  
              "name":"Daniela",
              "surname":"Mobily",
              "roleId":1,
              "id":3,
              "__uc__name":"DANIELA",
              "__uc__surname":"MOBILY",
              "_children":{  

              }
           }
        ]
     },
     "_clean":true,
     "_id":ObjectId("5508e3e0875cbdcc712feda5"),
     "id":1,
     "roleName":"employee"
  }
]
```

What is the expected result of this query:

```
db.roles.find().sort( {'_children.managers.name': 1 } )
```

The actual result is:

1) Slave

2) Employee

3) Boss

But... why? How does sorting actually work, in case where you sort by a key within an array with multiple elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ascending sort is working in exactly the way is should by considering the values present for the field reference you made within each item in the array and considering its value in comparison to other documents.

The ordering is probably best visualized when you consider the matched values from each document, in order they would be:

```js
{ "roleName": "SLAVE",    "_children.managers.name": null },
{ "roleName": "BOSS",     "_children.managers.name":"Tony" },
{ "roleName": "EMPLOYEE", "_children.managers.name":"Chiara" }
```

That is because that would be the "least" ( ascending ) ordered value for that field in each document.

When sorting on the "_children.managers.name" in ascending order the document results are:

```js
{ "roleName": "SLAVE",    "_children.managers.name": null },
{ "roleName": "EMPLOYEE", "_children.managers.name":"Chiara" }
{ "roleName": "BOSS",     "_children.managers.name":"Tony" },
```

Which is how you are seeing it.

So it's the "ordered" multi-key entry for the document value, and each value of the document considered against other.

Comment: Thank you Neil! Is this too obvious to be documented? Or is it somewhere in MongoDB's documentation?

Comment: @Merc The documentation could be better in a lot of areas. The closest thing you might find is under [Multkey indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/). But it's very abstract and not as concise. I had a go at submitting more descriptive examples some time back. There was a change and those were not committed. Which is most of the reason I am here.

Comment: Ouch.. thank you Neil! I am not s sure about MongoDB to be honest. They are well funded, why... why don't they invest time and efforts to create really good documentation?!?

Comment: @Merc this is not really productive to go into further discussion about. But for reference the reason given to me was "interns" would be contributing to documentation fixes. Community mailing lists and Q&A forums like this still have valid examples and explanations. So it's not like you did the wrong thing by asking.

Comment: I consider documentation the most important part of a project... I would never hand over the most important part of my project to some *interns*...! Oh well, thanks for the answer!